# How to use LESS with html attributes?

Tags: css, less

I have a lot of progress bars which I am currently using inline style to set the width. Is there a way for me to utilise data type with LESS or just CSS?

For example:

```
<div class="progress" aria-valuenow="3"></div>
<div class="progress" aria-valuenow="50"></div>
```

Can I do something like this in LESS/CSS:

```
.progress[aria-valuenow=x] {
    width: x%;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to use JavaScript for that.  Or make separate CSS selectors for every possible value.

Comment: The HTML5 `progress` element would be styled natively by browsers that support it, if that's OK with the semantics of your content. And I guess there must be polyfills out there.

Answer (score 3):

impossible to map a variable attribute value in css. can be done in less using a for loop but the output css would just be a ton of css for every possible value. my suggestion- if youre already applying the value inline using js, just apply that value to a style selector like width or translateX() and style youre progress bars accordingly

```
<div class="progress" width="x"></div>

 .progress {
    background: blue;
    transition: width 300ms;
}
```